# Django Deployment - Apache setup

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm working on deploying a django app and I'm looking at a few tutorials which install apache within the virtualenv.

http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/09/14/django-in-virtualenv-on-webfactions-apache-with-mod-wsgi/

My question is that if I'm trying to deploy to a server that already has Apache installed on it, would installing a separate version of apache within the environment (as you would Django in general) overwrite any of the Apache settings currently on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using virtualenv doesn't mean installing a separate version of Apache. In fact, that's not even possible, because virtualenv is for Python libraries only.

Your Django app plus all its libraries lives in the virtualenv, but you use the system's Apache to serve it.